# Pandas quantile function for dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of donation amounts and dates. I would like to see how long it took a certain proportion of the donations to come in (at what point did we have 25% of donations?, 75% ?). It looked like the Pandas quantile  function would do what I want.  However it seems to only want numbers, not dates. Is there a function that would do the same with dates ?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile

Comment: Is it not possible to (temporarily) convert the dates to a (Unix) timestamp, perform the quantile operation, and then convert the result back to a date(time) object?

Answer (score 6):

Like Evert say, you can convert it temporarily to int 64 compute and convert back to datetime

```
YOUR_DATAFRAME.YOUR_DATE.astype('int64').quantile([.25,.5,.75]).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case to split a timeseries for a machine learning problem.

I wrote the following based on the above answers by [evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707650/evert) and [steboc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3749146/steboc), and added the case where the dates might be written as strings:

```
def get_split_date(df, date_column, quantile): 

    """ Get the date on which to split a dataframe for timeseries splitting """ 

    # 1. convert date_column to datetime (useful in case it is a string) 
    # 2. convert into int (for sorting) 
    # 3. get the quantile 
    # 4. get the corresponding date
    # 5. return, pray that it works 

    quantile_date = pd.to_datetime(df[date_column], coerce = True).astype('int64').quantile(q=quantile).astype('datetime64[ns]')

    return quantile_date
```